# Making text and Integer input fields optional Swift

Tags: swift, core-data

Probably simple, but answer escapes me.

I have an IB with many input fields.  Some are text and some are integers.

I need to set these up so they are optional, as I want the user not be required to completed all fields.

This data will be saved in core data.

Here is the current chain of events:

```
@IBOutlet weak var diveSiteTextfield: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var diveDurationTextfield: UITextField!

-------
let dd = Int(diveDurationTextfield.text!)
let dd1 = Int32(dd!)

diveLogbook.diveSite = diveSiteTextfield.text
diveLogbook.diveDuration = dd1
```

The above are just an example on one text and one integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `?:` and `??` to provide default values for them:

```
diveLogbook.diveSite = diveSiteTextfield.text?.isEmpty ? "Default Dive Site" : diveSiteTextfield.text
diveLogbook.diveDuration = Int32(diveDurationTextfield.text!) ?? 5
```

Change the default values as needed.

Comment: Great, thanks on many levels.  Two followups:  The diveSite line does not as I get the error TextField as no member "isEmtpy".  Also, is it possible to set a default integer as blank?

Comment: Sorry my typo. And no, `Int` must have a value. You can change `diveDuration` to `Int?` and set it to `nil`

Comment: can you give an example on that nil statement?

Comment: Actually, 0 works fine.  I will set up the textfield to hide the result if is 0